# How to bypas isp "blocking" port forwarding (multiple devices, same ip)?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, home-networking, isp, self-hosting

My isp seems to assign 1 public ip to multiple users that are not on my network. which ruins port forwarding. Any way to bypass this. scanning my ip with nmap shows the desired port. but it doesn't work. there is also an ftp server which 100% isn't me.

Comment: Use a proxy or a vpn, other then that, there isnt a way to bypass a CGNAT configuration

Comment: You can ask the ISP for a static IP, then it won't be shared by others. This might require some payment.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. "

Comment: isps here are too greedy to give it for a small amount of money.

Comment: can't i setup a private vpn on a vm server to do this for free or i am officially screwed